# Bevel and emboss / inner shadow: How can I apply that same shading to the whole shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I have a deadline tonight and am struggling with this task.

I generally followed this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMtzPiPZN38&ab_channel=MockupArt), but worked on a white background instead. I copied the figure multiple times and scaled it down. Then I adjusted the color overlay values for each shape to make it look darker towards the middle.

I need the shadows / bevel & emboss must look across the whole shape exactly the same as in the red marked part.

Therefore, I copied the layer that contains the bevel & emboss / inner shadows and changed the angle from 45° to -90° and in another layer to 135°. This worked for bevel & emboss, but unfortunately not for the shadows. When I change the angle of the shadow in one layer, it applies also to all the other layers....

**How can I achieve the result, that the whole shape has the very same shading like the red marked part?**

[image: Original Shape]

[image: Task description]

[image: Layers Panel]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but how can I accept answers?? I do it as soon as I understand how... => Update: I found out how to do it and accepted the answers in previous posts

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure what you mean by "exactly the same".  The shapes look like they already have the same shading.  Do you mean you want to scale the shading with the shapes?  How have you constructed this? Can you share a screenshot of your layers panel?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your appreciated support. Please see layers panel in the picture above. Shape 1 was copied 11 times. towards the center I adjusted the color overlay settings, that the shape gets darker towards the center

Yes its the same settings for inner shading. The result is that these shadow settings make the red marked part darker then the rest of the shape. I know that this is standard with shadows, but it is not the result that I need. I need exactly the same shadowing also in the brighter parts. The whole shape must look the same.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. Your screenshot already looks like the shapes have the same shading. I'll ask again. Do you want to scale the shading with the shape?

Comment: Untick "use global light" to adjust each shadow without altering other shadows.

Comment: You could [flatten] slice it & rotate it, but it's going to look very unnatural, as it will lose the '3D-ness'.

Comment: Yes, left side should have same shadowing as right side
And also same bevel & emboss

Comment: The Bevel and Emboss and Shadow effects are directional and will not look the same in every direction. Perhaps it would be better to use an Inner Glow effect instead, [like this for exampe?](https://imgur.com/2Rrss98)

Comment: @Scott: Thank you for the untick "global light" trick / 

Billy Kerr: I will try inner glow effect. Hope that this will help! do you maybe have ideas with the settings I could apply?

Comment: The settings will depend on the size of your shape. You should try various settings until you get the result you want. If I just give you my settings, they are unlikely to be useful to you.

Comment: Really confused by your last image.. that's *exactly* what Bevel&Emboss are *supposed* to do - make one side darker and the opposing side lighter. Remove the Bevel&Emboss if that's not what you want. Or... set **both** the Highlight *and* Shadow modes to the same color, the same blend mode, and the same size in the Bevel&Emboss options - resulting in, essentially, an outer glow.

Comment: We don't do direct file swapping here. It would *quickly* be abused and untenable. In addition, many users get *paid* for their work. It's a bit unfair to expect them to work on your file for your project for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a 45 degree slice of your result (flattened) and make 7 rotated copies:

[image]

This one is made in Illustrator by starting from your screenshot. The seleced item is the used vector clipping mask which was sliced from a regular octagon.

The result can be pasted back to Photoshop without losing a single pixel of the resolution.

**The next one** is made in Illustrator. It's not just the same, but maybe it's good enough - at least, if you change the fill color of the smallest octagon to black:

[image]

The largest octagon was inserted at first with the polygon tool. It has thin black stroke and white fill color. Then a copy was made by applying Object > Transform > Scale > Uniform 80% > Copy

More copies was made by pressing Ctrl+D

All octagons were selected and Effect > Stylize > Inner Glow > Color = black, Blend = normal, Opacity = 100&, Edge  was applied. The good blur radius depends on the size of the shape. My starting octagon was 178 millimeters wide and the blur radius was 12,3 millimeters.

Inner glow is a raster effect. The resolution of the raster effects should be set high enough when starting the new drawing.

Figuring out this method may be tricky because the smallest octagon looks like it's the farthest in the background. In the object stack it's on the top.

Comment: Thanks. I was also thinking of this. The issue with this solution is, that I can not edit it right away anymore... But if I got you right: 1) export .png 2) cut out in Photoshop only the part that looks right 3) export as .png 4) paste in Illustrator and rotate it. Is the procedure correct? And, what do you mean with "45 degree slice of your result (flattened)"?

Comment: Your whole screenshot was pasted to Illustrator. You can make a Layer > Flatten: ed copy in Photoshop or preferably import the whole PNG (also a kind of flattened version of a multilayer PSD) to Illustrator. The vector shape you use to clip a sector in Illustrator must be exact 45 degrees to make 8 copies which are together total 360 degrees. Distorting the PNG in Illustrator a bit too big do not harm because the rotated copies of the clipped slice will fit & snap if the clipping mask was exactly a 45 degrees sector. Making the clipping and the rotated copies in Photoshop is difficult.

Comment: Thank you all!!